# Word Problem: If it rained 3.3 inches in a day. How much Did it rain within 4 hours+

Tags: arithmetic

I do not know how I should do this. Should I divide 3.3 into 4 hour or make a conversion factor such as 3.3/24hrs x 1hr/60min and then multiply the min by 4?

Comment: Logically, if all the problem is in hours units, why would you need to introduce minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1\mbox{ day }=6\times 4$ hours. So I suggest you to divide $3.3$ inches by $6$.

Comment: By 6.$\qquad\qquad$